# Weird lines in nginx's access log

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I get these two lines in my access log on ubuntu 16.04 with nginx every couple of hours. Could someone tell me what these mean?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2017:23:36:09 +0200] "POST /collect HTTP/1.0" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
<my external ip> - - [01/Aug/2017:23:36:09 +0200] "GET /collect HTTP/1.0" 404 564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Something on your server is POSTing to a URL on your web server, you're forwarding them to another URL. After that it looks like something is doing a GET on the same URL. You should look at the different software you have installed - someone may know what does this. I guess it could be malware, but it doesn't seem particularly likely.

Comment: If it's steadily every few hours, check your crontab for hints. And of course the collect script that is being called.